# Display message box if logged in or not?

Tags: html, vb.net, authentication, web

I have created a script that logs into a website, but now I need help. Here is the main script that logs me in, pretty self explanatory.

```
     WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login").SetAttribute("value", txtUsername.Text)
     WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("passwd").SetAttribute("value", txtPassword.Text)
     WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("SI").InvokeMember("Click")
```

Now, what I am trying to do is make it tell me if I have used the right log in or not (the website i'm using is live.com). So obviously I'm going to need something that can read the page, and if it finds this "That Microsoft account doesn't exist. Enter a different email address or get a new account." or this "That password is incorrect. Be sure you're using the password for your Microsoft account." then it should say something along the lines of this in a message box: "Could not log in". But if it's successful it should read something else, and also redirect it to a page. Can anyone give me any references or tips on how to start this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a browser's developer tool (for example, Firefox's Ctrl-Shift-I) to see the ID of the error message (in this case, "idTd_Tile_ErrorMsg_Login").

Then try `WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("idTd_Tile_ErrorMsg_Login")`. If that element's content is empty, there is no error message and login succeeded. Also, when you log in the page changes. So you can observe changes in the page URL, or see if the element (idTd_Tile_ErrorMsg_Login) can not be found.

Comment: Hmm, still a bit confused. So I use WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("idTd_Tile_ErrorMsg_Login") but then how do I get it to find out that the log in is invalid? Or did we just do that from finding the error message's name?